# Installing golang package from private gerrit repository

Tags: go, gerrit

I'm trying to use one of projects hosted in gerrit as a dependency in golang.

- I installed go-import plugin in gerrit
- I added this to .gitconfig:

```
[url "ssh://myuser@gerrit.example.com:29418"]
insteadOf = https://gerrit.example.com
```

Now I run:

```
go get gerrit.example.com/myproject
```

but it fails with:

```
go get: module gerrit.example.com/myproject: git ls-remote -q origin in /home/me/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/513f491cb527a8cec5b684e8d77254c851f76499e1f725440f98d4e9ad8bbf4f: exit status 128:
        fatal: project a/myproject not found
        fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that global git configuration is not setup with something along the lines:

```
git config --global url."git@gerrit.example.com:".insteadOf "https://gerrit.example.com"
```

**.gitconfig**

```
[url "git@gerrit.example.com"]
insteadOf = https://gerrit.example.com
```

For regular use of the git tool, it's convient to have a `~/.ssh/config` file set up. In order to do this, run the following commands:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
touch ~/.ssh/config
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

Please note the permissions on the files and directory above are essentail for SSH to work in it's default configuration on most Linux systems.

Then, edit the `~/.ssh/config` file to match the following:

```
Host gerrit.example.com
  HostName gerrit.example.com
  Port 29418
  User USERNAME_HERE
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_gerrit_example_com
```

Please note the spacing in the above file matters and will invalidate the file if it is incorrect.

Where `USERNAME_HERE` is your [`gerrit`](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/) username and `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is the path to your SSH private key in your file system. You've already uploaded its public key to [`gerrit`](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/).

**Note:** I have created this configuration just on assumption since i do not have [`gerrit`](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/) setup to test on.